# can PiNet provide other distibutions than Raspbian?

Tags: server, qemu

i'm aware that usual Ubuntu is recommended for the PiNet-server and Raspbian is served to the clients (Raspberry Pi's), but since [PiNet](http://pinet.org.uk) is something like an "advanced fat client solution" of Terminal Server... i'm asking **is it somehow possible to spread** Ubuntu MATE, or **other images** (like OSMC or LibreELEC) **to the clients?**

---

if not, makes it sense to look further in a direction using Raspberry Pi's Ubuntu MATE or OSMC via qemu/kvm on the server and spread it with the usual LTSP to the clients?

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at the [official documentation](http://pinet.org.uk/articles/guides.html). It seems like, it is a guide, how to install Pi-Net using Ubuntu Server. But the script which you have to install on the server automatically provides Raspbian to it's client-RasPi's, so I don't think it would be easy, using another distro, even though Raspbian and Ubuntu are both based on Debian.

But: If someone out here has made a positive experience about this, please tell us, I'm very interested in, if that works regardless of the ambition to just bring Raspbian to school.

Comment: for sure i read the documentation/guides and summarized the "recommendations" in my question... so it is clear that there won't be a "1-click-solution" but i asked *is it somehow possible*.

Comment: regarding *...if that works regardless of the ambition to just bring Raspbian to school.*: i'm not sure what you want to achieve but i'f you've got usual clients several cases are possible with [LTSP](http://ltsp.org/).